# Show image on error - WebView

Tags: android, webview

Hi i am using this code to show display                                       an image from drawable folder on error or no connection,

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
```

but the problem is, the image is not fitting on the screen, im using the right size but i have to scroll through the page to see the image.

Comment: Code is not enough to see how you are showing image

Comment: the image is just too big for the screen, i have to scroll left and right to see it